# Refresh div after posting a comment

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

I would like to add a comment and show it right away in a thread using ajax

here is my code:

JSP:

```
<div class="comments">
     //Here i show the list of comments
    <logic:iterate id="comment" name="discussion" property="comments">
        <div class='comment'>
            <div class='title'> ${comment.author.firstName}<br>
                ${comment.date}</div>
            <div class='commentContent'>
                ${comment.content}
            </div>              
        </div>
    </logic:iterate>
</div>

//this is my comment form
<html:form action="/sauvegarderCommentaire.do" styleId="formComment">
    <label>Ecrire un commentaire:</label>
    <br>
    <textarea name="comment"> </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitComment" />
</html:form>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#submitComment").click(
     function() {
         $("#formComment").ajaxSubmit({
                 error : function() {
                         alert("Il y a une erreur AJAX");
                 },
                 success: function(e) {                               
                           //Here I try to reload only the comments part of my page
                          $(".comments").load("/myApp/discussion.do .comments");
                 }
         });            
});
```

I hope I'm clear?!!
Otherwise I can provide some more details :)

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error at all, its just not showing the comment the the person just posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

First add id to your textarea.

```
<textarea name="comment" id="tar"></textarea>
```

Replace your jquery code with this.

```
$('#submitComment').click(function() {
var tar = $('#tar').val();
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/myApp/discussion.do", //url where u want to send the request
    data : { tar : tar },
    success : function(resp){
        $('.commentContent').html(resp);
    },
    error : function(resp){
        alert("Error AJAX");
    }        
});
$(".comments").load("/myApp/discussion.do .comments");  
});
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work! I think the problem is that I'm not getting the new list of comments, cuz when I refresh the page the new comment appears

Comment: you haven't mentioned type and URL in ur ajax.

Comment: I thought the load() will go to the servlet reload the discussion object and thus I get the new list of comments! seems like that's not the case!??

Comment: Sorry for last comment, actually the url and data are mentioned in the form: action="/sauvegarderCommentaire.do", look at the jsp part
And when I call ajaxSubmit on the form, it gets submitted

Comment: That is almost the same thing, u just changed the syntax! what Im looking for is when i update the discussion object(which contains the comments list) I would like to get it back updated which is not happening for the moment

Comment: To understand my goal, u can look at youtube comment system, thats what im trying to implement

Comment: $('.commentContent').html(resp); This line will put your comments into your comment box. and try once removing the .load after ajax. Bcoz this code Should Work.. If u want reference see this thread stackoverflow.com/questions/22660712/how-to-include-jsp-with-dynamic-value-on-ajax-servlet-call

Comment: Thnks for the reference!